# Rails update database field according to two other fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sql-update, vote

So I have 2 fields in my Articles table.

```
- :vote_up
- :vote_down
```

I have methods in my app of updating the :vote_up and :vote_down fields that work fine. What I want to do is order my articles by total votes (:vote_up minus :vote_down).

What is the best way to do this. Can I do this directly in the controller with a certain method? Or must I create a :vote_total field that updates automatically according to the values of the other two fields (if so how do you do this).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this in your controller. This is meant to be done in your model. Controllers should just use the model.

You can do this in 2 ways:

**Solution 1**

Try this in your console (rails c)

```
Article
  .unscoped
  .select(%q(articles.*, (articles.vote_up - articles.vote_down) AS vote_total))
  .order(%q(vote_total DESC))
```

and the implement it as a scope in your `Article` class

```
scope :order_by_total_votes, -> {
   select(%q(articles.*, (articles.vote_up - articles.vote_down) AS vote_total))
  .order(%q(vote_total DESC))
}
```

**Solution 2**

Create a field `vote_total` for your `Article` and update it every time one of the vote fields gets updated (use a `before_save` callback). Then you can do the same as in solution 1, but without the `select` part.

**Suggestion**

I would go with solution 2, because amongst others it is faster in queries

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thinks for this. I ended up doing solution 2 but slightly different. Have posted my working answer below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Hiasinho for your direction. I ended up just creating a :vote_total to my Article database and updated it on both my upvote and downvote methods like so

```
@article.update_attributes(vote_total: @article.vote_total + 1)
```

Obviously it was a -1 for downvotes.